# C# facebook extend long-lived access token expiration day by renewing

Tags: facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

Currently I am working with long-lived access token (60 day expiration long-lived).

I see a post in facebook I can extend long-lived access token by first getting back short-lived access token and then renewing it to new long-lived token.
I hope this can be done without user getting involved. (user doesn't have to log in and give the permissions again for this process)

Has anybody done this in c#?

It would be greatly appreciated if you can share code or link.

Here is the instruction from facebook website:

"If you would like to refresh a still valid long-lived access_token, you will have to get a new short-lived user access_token first and then call the same endpoint below. The returned access_token will have a fresh long-lived expiration time, however, the access_token itself may or may not be the same as the previously granted long-lived access_token."

And here is some example posted right below the instruction which I am not familiar with how to use:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Website source: http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 0):

> […] y first getting back short-lived access token and then renewing it to new long-lived token. I hope this can be done without user getting involved.

No, of course it can **not**, at least not without *any* user interaction.

You have to at least have the user visit one of you pages, where you can check his login status client-side and get a short-lived access token in return if he is still connected to your app.

Comment: Even for desktop apps or for device?  I see facebook is preparing another authentication method for Device.